# Draw arrow on 360 image for direction of tour Threejs

Tags: three.js, virtual-tour

I want to create a scene where user can view 360 image of particular place.

Requirement: Draw arrow when user click on particular area for direction.

Problem: on click, it generates arrow suppose on DOOR but when we change scene to other position, arrow not sticky to last position, so I want arrow to be on same place.

Anyone can take example of 360 tour of place where direction arrow clickable. but here arrow will be created dynamically on scene.

Please help!!

Using: **ThreeJS**